# BizTalk 2020 Saxon XSLT 3.0 Transformation exception

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk, saxon, biztalk-2020

I am trying to work on a Proof of concept to run the BizTalk map using saxon xslt 3.0
There is a method where we can use custom extensions (xml) Extension objects to execute a method.

I am following this link but getting an error when performing **TestMap**

> Invalid extension class Test.TestMethod for Saxon transform, it should be type of "ExtensionFunction" or "ExtensionFunctionDefinition"

[BizTalk Server 2020: A review of the new XSLT 3.0 & Custom Transform Features: Custom Engine Options](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53591.biztalk-server-2020-a-review-of-the-new-xslt-3-0-custom-transform-features.aspx#Custom_Extensions) (social.technet.microsoft.com)

Custom Extension xml

```
<ExtensionObjects>
<ExtensionObject Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/ScriptNS0" AssemblyName="Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=11f992b93de945f2,processorArchitecture=MSIL" ClassName="Test.TestMethod" /></ExtensionObjects>
```

Anything is missing in the custom extension xml file?
I am not sure what is wrong here.

Note: I get the same error at run time after deploying the application in BizTalk 2020

Comment: How does your code look? Have you implemented `ExtensionFunctionDefinition` and `ExtensionFunctionCall`? And shouldn't `ClassName="Test.TestMethod"` rather name e.g. `ClassName="MyNamespace.MyExtensionClass"`? But the latter depends on how your code looks so show that in your question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : yes I tried to implement(ExtensionFunctionDefinition and ExtensionFunctionCall) using the same example --CSharpExtension class. In that example link,are your referring to MyExtensionClass as 'ExtensionFunctionDefinition' ?

Comment: No, the class that implements `ExtensionFunctionDefinition` e.g. from the example it is `CSharpExtensions.Sqrt`. In that example `CSharpExtensions` is the namespace and `Sqrt` is the name of the class in that namespace that implements `ExtensionFunctionDefinition`.

Comment: Yes,I have implemented in c#. Just used a different class and method names.Rest all same